# Import Oracle .dmp file using SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to import a `.dmp` file exported from another database, and I was wondering if anyone have experience on using GUI import option for `.dmp` file from SQL Developer? I have searched a lot of documents, but I couldn't find any detail. I can use SYS or SYSTEM user to import.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

what was this another database? was it oracle database? 
if yes 
the dmp file can be file exported by

1. DataPump [expdp](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/dp_export.htm) util and you need import it by using [impdp](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/dp_import.htm) util
2. the file can be exported by [exp](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96652/ch01.htm) util and you can import it by [imp](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96652/ch02.htm) util
3. how to use this DataPump utils via SQL Developer UI see [here](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/sqldev/r31/datapump_OBE/datapump.html)

Answer (score 0):

Simple and easy step

Set Oracle Home Path in env.property

ORACLE_HOME = Path

```
imp 'sys/admin AS SYSDBA' file=C:\Oracle_DB_Dump.dmp full=Y
```